# How to submit form with SSL from non SSL page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl

I have read that you cannot make an ajax call from an http served page to an https page. But how does reddit do this?

When you click log in it makes an ajax call to https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login

When I try to do this on a local test machine firebug comes back with the status as 'aborted' in the NET tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [CORS](http://www.google.tt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fcors%2F&ei=OxUXUIPADY-i8ATCtYAg&usg=AFQjCNGENlRdQ3w0oFhUxIWgiJgyZfpoyA&sig2=mdnVcvnB3pJKZFmA5-Jl6w) here are the headers from `https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login/tester`

```
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-origin:http://www.reddit.com
```

Comment: Thank you I think you are right. Now to figure out this `access-control-allow-XXX` buisness.